# element doesn't exist in the DOM, isPresent() should return false,but it doesn't. Protractor hangs inside then() block and jasmine spec times out

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, angular10

In my page, there is a welcome modal that covers the navbar. I want to test the navbar functionality so I should close the modal first to be able to click on the navbar.

1. The protractor runs the 1st test: `cancel-icon(close button)` exist in the DOM > isPresent() returns `true` > Protractor clicks on it and close the modal (It gets removed from the DOM). Everything is OK.
2. It runs the 2nd test and the browser gets the page again. This time `cancel-icon(close button)` doesn't exist in the DOM because it was removed on the previous step >  isPresent() should return false but it hangs and return nothing till the Jasmine spec times out > The test fails.

This is my code:

```js
describe('My test', function () { 
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get(url);
    });

    it('The user clicks on `Discover` in navbar, app-feed-discover should be displayed.', async function () {
        let result = await element(by.id('cancel-icon')).isPresent();
        if (result) await element(by.id('cancel-icon')).click();
        await element(by.css('app-feed-item-component:nth-of-type(1) > div')).click();
        expect(element(by.css('app-feed-discover')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('The user clicks on `Products` in navbar, app-products-discover should be displayed.', async function () {
        let result = await element(by.id('cancel-icon')).isPresent();
        if (result) await element(by.id('cancel-icon')).click();
        await element(by.css('app-feed-item-component:nth-of-type(2) > div')).click();
        expect(element(by.css('app-products-discover')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I got this error:

```
[11:21:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:21:18] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:21:19] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.5.199:50919/wd/hub
Started
.FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.


Failures:
1) My test The user clicks on `Products` in navbar, app-products-discover should be displayed.
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 247.172 seconds

[11:25:28] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[11:25:28] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:25:28] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:25:28] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[11:25:28] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

It's my conf.js

```js
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['final.js'],
    getPageTimeout: 30000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);
    },
    multiCapabilities: [
        {browserName: 'chrome'}
    ]
}
```

- Node Version: `v14.15.3`
- Protractor Version: `v7.0.0`
- Angular Version: `v10.0.3`
- Browser(s): `Chrome`
- Operating System and Version `MacOS Catalina v10.15.7`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out how to recognise elements that don’t exist on the DOM!! It's pretty easy!

While isPresent() doesn’t work properly if an element doesn’t exist, we can use `browser.executeScript` instead. It works fine!

```
let result = await browser.executeScript(`return document.getElementById("some-id")`);
```

Needless to say, returns the element if finds it. If not, returns `null`.